# Perl xor returns unexpected result

Tags: perl, xor

What's going on here?  Why isn't $c == 1 ?

```
$ cat y.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
$a = 0;
$b = 1;
$c = $a xor $b;
print "$a ^ $b = $c\n";

$ ./y.pl 
0 ^ 1 = 0
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!!

Comment: Also: Don't use single letter variable names. If you _must_ then `$a` and `$b` are bad choices, because they're used by `sort`.

Answer (score 11):

Always use

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
```

It would have detected your precedence issue.

```
Useless use of logical xor in void context
```

Specifically,

```
$c = $a xor $b;
```

means

```
($c = $a) xor $b;
```

The operators `and`, `or`, `not` and `xor` have very low precedence. This makes `and`, `or` and `not` very useful for flow control.

```
... or die ...;
... or next;
```

`xor` doesn't short-circuit, so it's not useful for flow control.  `xor` was created for an entirely different reason. Like `or`, `xor` is a logical operator. That means considers the truth of its operand as whole instead of doing bit-by-bit comparisons. I don't believe this is the operation you want.

Fix:

```
$c = $a ^ $b;
```

---

```
                                    Low
                                    Precedence
Operation   Bitwise     Logical     Logical
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
NOT         ~           !           not
AND         &           &&          and
OR          |           ||          or
OR*         N/A         //          N/A
XOR         ^           N/A         xor

OR* - Like OR, but only undefined is considered false.
```

Answer (score 2):

Precedence of the assignment is higher than xor. Just write:

```
$c = ($a xor $b);
```

Comment: ... which `use strict; use warnings` tells you, and is why you should always use it.

Comment: `1 xor 3` returns false  (`dualvar(0, "")`) because `xor` is a logical operator. I On the other hand, `1 ^ 3` returns `2` because `^` is a bitwise operator. I think the OP wants the latter, though it's hard to tell from their example, though.